Precise statement of the **Substitution Law** for Conditional Expectation
Elementary probability books provide the following "substitution law" for conditional expectation:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|X=t] = E[f(t,Y)|X=t].
\tag{1}
\label{eq:law}
\end{align}
$$
Given the known limitations [1] of this law, I am interested in a more rigorous statement. Here is my attempt:
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and
$Z:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be random variables.
The conditional expectation of $Z$ given $X$, denoted $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]$, is any $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable such that
\begin{align}
\int \mathbf{1}_A (\omega) \mathbb{E}[Z|X](\omega)\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega) = 
\int \mathbf{1}_A (\omega) Z(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)
&& (A \in \sigma(X)).
\end{align}
By the Doob-Dynkin Lemma, there exists a measurable function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[Z|X] \equiv h(X)$, $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely. This function $h(t)$ is then denoted $\mathbb{E}[Z|X=t]$.
In the setting of \eqref{eq:law}, our random variable $Z = f(X,Y)$ for some $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.  Now, for each $x$, we know from the previous paragraph that there exists a function $h_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h_x(X) \equiv \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)\mid X]$ a.s., and we may denote this function by $h_x(t) = \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)|X=t]$.
Defining $h(t) = \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|X=t]$ as before, it seems then that \eqref{eq:law} claims that
\begin{align}
h(t) = h_t(t) && (\mbox{a.e}).
\end{align}

Is this argument correct?

Can anyone provide a reference for the general result? I checked the usual books (e.g., Durrett, Billingsley) who list many properties of conditional expectation, but not this one. Shiryaev shows that $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|X=t] = \mathbb{E}[f(t,Y)]$ a.e., when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.



References
[1] Expect the Unexpected from Conditional Expectation
Michael A. Proschan, Brett Presnell
The American Statistician, Vol. 52, No. 3 (Aug., 1998), pp. 248-252 (5 pages)
https://doi.org/10.2307/2685937. (Note: Section 4: Substitution Fallacy).
[2] Gubner, John A. Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK. Example 13.23 revised. https://gubner.ece.wisc.edu/books/ProbRandProc/example13.23revision.pdf

The subscript at your function $h_x$ changes so many times from $x$ to $t$ and vice versa that one gets dizzy. Before you ask the first question you are trying to reformulate (1) with some other notation. That is all I can see. (1) itself is perfectly formulated. The question is: is it true? I think it is: obviously true for functions $f(x,y)$ of the form $u(x)v(y),.$ Then use a monotone class argument to extend this to more general $f,.$ This is also the method of proof for the known result you found in Shiryaev.

The article [1] costs 44 USD to read. What exactly are those authors saying about the "limitations" of (1) ?

Apologies for the typo involving $h_x$, it has been fixed in the post. Regarding formulating (1) in some other notation: the idea is to give a precise meaning to the RHS of (1) rather than the "informal" meaning in elementary probability. Regarding [1], the essence of the limitation is that $\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)|X=x]$ is only unique a.e. $x$, which means interpreting its values at a given $x$ is meaningless.

Glad that I did not spend 44 bucks to buy that red herring. You mentioned the Doob-Dynkin lemma which gives to both sides of (1) the most precise meaning I can think of. That functions which are only interesting under an integral with a continuous measure need to be unique only a.e. is nothing specific to conditional expectation.

It is not entirely a red herring. There is some substance for when properties such as (1) hold. E.g., "A Note on Substitution in Conditional Distribution." Michael D. Perlman, Michael J. Wichura. The Annals of Statistics, Vol. 3, No. 5 (Sep., 1975), pp. 1175-1179 (5 pages) https://www.jstor.org/stable/2958371. The best reference I can find is Theorem 8.5 in Kallenberg's Foundation of Modern Probability (3rd Ed), which establishes the result in the presence of regular conditional distributions.
